# Supersized Jquery conflict with background image

Tags: jquery, wordpress, supersized, nextgen-gallery

I have a problem with a wordpress site that uses nextgen gallery(powered by supersized)
So I have created a div to manage the background image

```
<div>
<img id="backgroundx" title="" alt="" src="wp-content/uploads/2012/09/DSC_5269.jpg"/>
</div>
```

and it's css is

```
#backgroundx {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1001;
}
```

Everything is fine but when I enter a NextGEN category ( for example http://newlightphotography.org/category/bambini-2 ) it doesn't display the background
But every other page (including expanded gallery http://newlightphotography.org/madalina-149 ) work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's weird that those two pages have different image behavior, you may find this quick fix acceptable:

```
<div>
<img id="backgroundx" title="" alt="" src="/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/DSC_5269.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Simply add a root slash before wp-content.